# Flip sprite vertically AND horizontally?

Tags: xna, c#, xna-4.0

In `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.SpriteEffects` there is the possibility to flip a texture horizontally or vertically before rendering. But can one do both at the same time?

When I use: `spriteEffect = SpriteEffects.FlipHorizontally | SpriteEffects.FlipVertically;` with `spriteEffect` being a parameter of the particle. The method `spriteBatch.Draw(spriteSheet,
                        currentPositionForDraw,
                        sourceRectangle,
                        currentColorMultiplied,
                        currentRotation,
                        currentOriginForDraw,
                        Temp.delta,
                        spriteEffect,
                        0);` does not draw the particle flipped on both axis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. If you look at the definition of that enum you'll see it has [[FlagsAttribute]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/enum-flags-attribute) which means you can combine the enum values with the | operator.

Comment: Sorry, but how do I do that ?

Comment: SpriteEffects.FlipHorizontally | SpriteEffects.Flipvertically

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: @pad You edited the question to suggest that this answer is insufficient, but it's still marked as correct. Which is it?

Answer (score 7):

If you don't care about rotation, you can simply set the origin of the sprite to its center and rotate it 180 degrees (`Math.PI`). This is the same as flipping horizontally and vertically.

If you *do* care about rotation, and the sprite is flipped both ways, you can just add `Math.PI` to the angle and you should be done (eg. 45 degrees + 180 degrees rotation looks the same as 45-degrees flipped on both axes).